# Getting data from HTML

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I have the following HTML

```
<p class="race-description">
        Racing Uk's Profits Returned To Racing Handicap (5)
        </p>
<p class="clearer race-info">
    <span>Going: SOFT Â |Â </span>
    <span>Distance: 6f Â |Â </span>
    <span>Age: 3yo+ Â |Â </span>
    <span>Total prize money: Â£5000 Â |Â </span>
    <span>Runners: 10 Â |Â </span>
    <span>Race Type: Flat</span>
</p>
```

This is output using the following code

```
//pull the data for the race
$getdropdown22  = '//div[contains(@class, "content")]/p';
$getdropdown222 = $xpath->query($getdropdown22);
//loop through each individual card
foreach ($getdropdown222 as $dropresults2) {
  echo $racename = $dropresults2->c14n();
}
```

`$racename = $dropresults2->c14n();` is echoing the HTML you see above. What I want to do is get the data from the first paragraph (in this case Racing Uk's Profits Returned To Racing Handicap (5)) and I want to get the data from the second paragraph in this case the below:

```
<span>Going: SOFT Â |Â </span>
                    <span>Distance: 6f Â |Â </span>
                    <span>Age: 3yo+ Â |Â </span>
                    <span>Total prize money: Â£5000 Â |Â </span>
                    <span>Runners: 10 Â |Â </span>
                    <span>Race Type: Flat</span>
```

but I want to get the text from each span into separate variables.

I can get the first paragraph by doing the following:

```
 echo $racename = trim($dropresults2->childNodes->item(0)->textContent);
```

but if I change item(0) to item(1) (which I would assume is the second paragraph) I get nothing?? - I would then assume once I have the second paragraph I would be able to extract the data using the following:

```
$dropresults2->childNodes->item(??)->childNodes->item(*fill with span number*)->textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think the assumption that `$dropresults2->childNodes->item(1)` means the second paragraph element is wrong.

DOMDocument will allow you to iterate over all elements in an HTML fragment, even empty ones, and looking closely at the markup, the first paragraph element is immidately followed by a break element (`<br/>`). I suspect that this is what is being referred to.

If this is correct, then `$dropresults2->childNodes->item(2)` should get you the second paragraph element, from which you should then be able to traverse it's child span elements, fetching the text content from each in turn.

**EDIT:**

After some discussion it was clear that rather than being a containing element, `$dropresults2`, the value of the iterator, was actually being set to each paragraph node in turn, resulting in errors after the first iteration, but returning expected data for the second. In this case,

`$dropresults2->childNodes->item(0)->textContent` actually represented the Text Node for the contents of the first paragraph element, which is why this was being returned, and then all of the contents of the second paragraph element were being returned on the second iteration.

Comment: i have tried `$dropresults2->childNodes->item(2)` and get Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/runningp/public_html/mr-tipster/Results/pullresultpagecodes.php on line 36

Comment: Also intrestingly if i do `$dropresults2->childNodes->item(7) ` i get Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/runningp/public_html/mr-tipster/Results/pullresultpagecodes.php on line 36
Total prize money: Â£5000 Â |Â    (<- it seems to give me an error but still output the text)

Comment: It might be worth working out what is actually being returned in the DOMNodeList that represents the children of `$dropresults2`. Maybe something like (pseudo):

    `foreach ($dropresults2->childNodes as $node) {`
        `if(is_object($node)) {`
               `echo $node->nodeType;`
        `} else {`
              `echo $node;`
       `}`
   `}`

Comment: I ran the above and get the output 33131313131313

Comment: [DOMNode->nodeType](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodetype) tells you that you can use the list [here](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.constants.php) to work out the types of nodes that are represented here - DOMDocument seems to be interpreting a lot of the content as `DOMText` nodes (value 3) and only some as actual `DOMElements` (value 1); from those that are `DOMElements` you can use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#domelement.props.tagname) to work out which elements are being found here.

Comment: interesting so would i need to use tagName to get the value? (its what the bottom link is going too)

Comment: No, simply use tagname in order to work out what elements are being found here out of the ones available (`<p>`,`<br/>` and `<span>`) - this should give you a better idea of how DOMDocument is interpreting your HTML fragment and allow you to work out how to drill down to the elements you need

Comment: Sorry Ben but how would I do that??  I have tried `$dropresults2->getElementsByTagName("p")->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83860/discussion-between-benjamin-and-emma-perkins).